# HTML Bootstrap website's background color not changing, and also how to add in social network buttons

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem here.  One of my friends was helping me with Bootstrap stuff for my website, but after converting my site to Bootstrap, I can no longer change my background color in my website.  Will someone please help me?  Thanks a ton!  Oh, and also, while at it, how would I create a Facebook social link with the Facebook icon on, as well as when hovering over the icon there is another color?  Thanks again!

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge,chrome-1">
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="About%20Me.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Pictures.html">Pictures</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Contacts.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>

    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="Images/Image10.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Near my house: a meadow</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="Images/Image4.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Flume Gorge: A Waterfall</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="Images/Image3.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Flume Gorge: The Forest</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
        </div>
        </div>

    <footer class="text-center">
        <div class="footer-above">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        <h3>Location</h3>
                        <p>School Address: Not Availible</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        <h3>Connect with Social Media!</h3>
                        <div>
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MyUsername"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        <h3>About Bootstrap</h3>
                        <p>Bootstrap is a free open source project that help simplifies the creation of websites</p>
                        <p><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Get Bootstrap Now</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-below">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Copyright &copy; Name 2015-2016
                       <p> All music used on this site belongs to the respective authors</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #777;
}

#carousel-example-generic{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for the firs question this is all what you need :

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

for the second question you can use **[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/facebook/)**

here is an exemple I created on how to change the color on hover on social media icons :

```
<div class="background">
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-facebook"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-youtube"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-linkedin"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/np9cLgL8/)**

EDIT : link updated !

Comment: I know about the background-color but when I tried to do it before it wouldn't work....and I don't know why but the background color is not changing.  But thanks for the help on the icons!

Comment: try to use important like so ... background-color: black !important;

Answer (score 0):

To make a facebook button i would use [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).
Fontawesome provides you a lot of icons, similar to bootstrap glyphicon, to wich you can also apply some CSS to make them appear as you want.

To do this you have to:

1) Link the fontawesome file, adding this to your `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

2) Choose your icon from [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) and insert it anywhere you want, in a button or an anchor to your web page.
For example, if you will choose "facebook-official", you just have to insert this in your html

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>
```

For example:

```
<a id="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com">
 <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i>
</a>

#fb{
 background-color: blue;
}
#fb:hover{
 background-color: red;
}
```

This will make a link to the fabook home page, that if hovered will became red

Hoping to have helped.